Trouble finding extreme points in multi-interval Remez algorithm for sign function approximation
I am trying to understand the multi-interval Remez algorithm as described in this paper to approximate the sign function. However, I am encountering a problem when trying to find the extreme points of the approximating polynomial. Specifically, instead of obtaining $d+2$) points (where $d$ is the degree of the polynomial) as expected, I end up with less points.
To illustrate, to approximate the sign function with a polynomial of degree five over the range  $D = [-1, -0.5] \cup [0.5, 1]$ using a basis of Chebyshev polynomials, I start by picking seven Chebyshev points over the range D (four points from $[-1, -0.5]$ and three from $[0.5, 1]$) which produces the following approximating polynomial.
Graph of approximating polynomial of degree five.
Based on the graph given above I get the following graph for the error function $e(x) = f(x) - p(x)$,  where $f(x)$ is the sign function and $p(x)$ is the  polynomial of degree five created in the first iteration of the algorithm.
Graph of function e(x).
Just like in the single interval Remez algorithm a set of extreme points will be picked for the next iteration based on $e(x)$. Because the set of possible extreme points includes the endpoints from two ranges this often means we end up with more than $d+2$ candidate points and we need to select the best ones.
$e(x)$ has three points where the derivative is zero, points $(e, f, g )$ and four endpoints, points $(a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2)$. However, when I use the concavity function to filter out points that do not satisfy the local extreme value condition, I end up discarding all the endpoints. For example, $e(x)$ at point $a_1$ is concave and has a negative value, meaning that the algorithm thinks it is a local maximum that is negative. Which means that I end up with three extreme points instead of the seven extremes I should end up with according to the algorithm.
To address this, I tried the following approach:

Find all points where the first derivative of the error function is zero (the set $X = [x_1, ..., x_{d+2}]$).
Apply the second derivative test to filter out positive minima and negative maxima from the set $X$.
Ensure the alternation condition is met by verifying that sign($x_i$) $\cdot$ sign($x_{i+1}$) $= -1$ for $i = 1,..,d+1$.
Finally, select $n+1$ points that satisfy the maximum absolute error condition.

Is this a valid approach to solve the problem, or is there a better method I should consider? Alternatively, am I misunderstanding some aspect of the algorithm?
Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!
